# Solving video classification problem by taking EVA Large as backbone

Tags: classification, cnn, pytorch, computer-vision, transformer

I am solving a video classification problem. There are 9 classes in total. At first I took ResNet as a feature extractor, this gave me 0.74 accuracy. Then I changed ResNet to EVA (I also tried Swin), hoping that this would increase accuracy. But this greatly worsened the result. That's my model:

```py
class RSNAModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained=True):
        super(RSNAModel, self).__init__()

        self.backbone = timm.create_model(model_name=Config['FEATURE_EXTRACTOR'], pretrained=True, num_classes=0)
        freeze_module(self.backbone)
        
        
        self.num_features = self.backbone.num_features
        self.backbone.classifier = Identity()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=Config['DR_RATE'])
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=self.num_features, 
            hidden_size=self.num_features // 2, 
            num_layers=1,
            dropout=Config['RNN_DP'],
            bidirectional=True,
            batch_first=True, 
        )
        
        self.head = nn.Linear(in_features=self.num_features, out_features=Config['NUM_CLASSES'])
        
    def forward(self, inputs):
        b, f, c, h, w = inputs.shape
        inputs = inputs.reshape(b * f, c, h, w)
        embeddings = self.backbone(inputs)
        embeddings = embeddings.reshape(b, f, self.num_features)
        sequence_outputs, h_n = self.rnn(embeddings)
        features = sequence_outputs[:, -1]
        outputs = self.dropout(features)
        outputs = self.head(outputs)
        
        return outputs
```

```
==========================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
==========================================================================================
RSNAModel                                [4, 9]                    --
├─Beit: 1-1                              [64, 1408]                363,264
│    └─PatchEmbed: 2-1                   [64, 256, 1408]           --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-1                  [64, 1408, 16, 16]        (829,312)
│    │    └─Identity: 3-2                [64, 256, 1408]           --
│    └─Dropout: 2-2                      [64, 257, 1408]           --
│    └─ModuleList: 2-3                   --                        --
│    │    └─Block: 3-3                   [64, 257, 1408]    
          ............
│    │    └─Block: 3-42                  [64, 257, 1408]           (25,248,768)
│    └─Identity: 2-4                     [64, 257, 1408]           --
│    └─LayerNorm: 2-5                    [64, 1408]                (2,816)
│    └─Identity: 2-6                     [64, 1408]                --
├─LSTM: 1-2                              [4, 16, 1408]             11,906,048
├─Dropout: 1-3                           [4, 1408]                 --
├─Linear: 1-4                            [4, 9]                    12,681
==========================================================================================
Total params: 1,023,064,841
Trainable params: 11,918,729
Non-trainable params: 1,011,146,112
Total mult-adds (G): 63.75
==========================================================================================
Input size (MB): 38.54
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 62167.32
Params size (MB): 3138.77
Estimated Total Size (MB): 65344.63
==========================================================================================
```

What should i do to improve results? What other tricks can be applied to improve accuracy?  I believe that a good vision transformer as backbone can improve accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

The current state-of-the-art are transformer architectures. One example is [ViViT: A Video Vision Transformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15691) which has an implementation
[ViViT-pytorch](https://github.com/rishikksh20/ViViT-pytorch).

Something like this:

```py
from vivit import * 

class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, depth, heads, dim_head, mlp_dim, dropout = 0.):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([])
        self.norm = nn.LayerNorm(dim)
        for _ in range(depth):
            self.layers.append(nn.ModuleList([
                PreNorm(dim, Attention(dim, heads = heads, dim_head = dim_head, dropout = dropout)),
                PreNorm(dim, FeedForward(dim, mlp_dim, dropout = dropout))
            ]))

    def forward(self, x):
        for attn, ff in self.layers:
            x = attn(x) + x
            x = ff(x) + x
        return self.norm(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I have just stopped training because val loss at the 40th epoch about 3.5 https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Zul0pJxja_IrNnt5ol1BunU0-_MbRCbP?usp=sharing Could you look at it and say what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe increasing the dropout will fix these problems? And is it worth increasing batch_size? Now batch_size=4, because there are only 450 training and 80 test videos in the dataset.